# Java8 Swing Change Color of jToggle Button

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, button

In IntelliJ I am using Java8 and JavaSwing (GUI). I have a jToggle button that I want to change colors depending on whether it is clicked or not. I am fine with the shape and curved corners of the button, and just want to generic blue color of the button changed.
I currently have:

```
laserOnOff.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
laserOnOff.setOpaque(true);
laserOnOff.setBorderPainted(false);
```

but this changes the button shape and when I toggle the button, only the background of the text changes color.
I have also tried

```
UIManager.put("ToggleButton.select", Color.GREEN);
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(laserOnOff);
```

But that did not work.
What is a simple way to be able to change the color of a jToggle button?

(In the attached images, I want the button to look like the one on the right, just with the green color)
[image: What the jToggle button looks like if it is selected.]
[image: jToggle Button not selected]

Comment: Short answer is kind of - no.  The body been painted is specific to the Look And Feel and not Swing itself

Comment: @MadProgrammer can you elaborate?

Comment: The `contentAreaFilled` property determines if the platform look and feel paints any "additional" content (the fancy border and shading), it, how ever, rarely considers the background color, which is the color which fills the rest of the button.  You could try look at the `ButtonUI` for the platform, but this becomes a mess, as you need to take into consideration every look and feel delegate

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I misunderstood your question. Nonetheless here is a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of a *Swing* application that contains a single `JToggleButton`. Initially the button has a white background and its text is **Laser Off**. When the user clicks on the button, the text changes to **Laser on** and the background color changes to green. When the user clicks on the button a second time, the text reverts to **Laser off** and the background color also reverts to white. Hence the button continually toggles its text and background color with every successive activation of the button. I hope this helps you.

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JToggleButton;
import javax.swing.UIDefaults;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class TogglTst implements ActionListener, Runnable {

    @Override // java.lang.Runnable
    public void run() {
        createAndShowGui();
    }

    @Override // java.awt.event.ActionListener
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actnEvnt) {
        Object src = actnEvnt.getSource();
        JToggleButton toggle = (JToggleButton) src;
        if (toggle.isSelected()) {
            toggle.setText("Laser On");
        }
        else {
            toggle.setText("Laser Off");
        }
    }

    private void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JSP");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createButtonsPanel(), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.setSize(450, 300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createButtonsPanel() {
        JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
        JToggleButton toggle = new JToggleButton("Laser Off");
        toggle.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        toggle.addActionListener(this);
        buttonsPanel.add(toggle);
        return buttonsPanel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UIDefaults dflts = UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults();
        dflts.put("ToggleButton.select", Color.GREEN);
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new TogglTst());
    }
}
```